# Replying to comments

Tags: comments

As the administrator for our blog, can I post replies to comments as someone else. If so, how do I do this? Each time I try to post a reply, it says it is coming from me and I want it to look as if it is coming from the author.

Comment: Login as the other person.

Answer (score 1):

Comments automatically use credentials of logged in user.

You have two options:

1. Log out of your account and leave a comment like a regular user.
2. Log in into different account via native means or use a plugin that allows you to switch between accounts.

Answer (score 0):

[User switching](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/) plugin might ease the the pain while switching users.